# Prove the straight line as a tangent to a parabola.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

I was going through some past exam papers and I came across this problem and I'm bit puzzled on how to approach this, could someone please help me out?

Equation of the parabola $y^2-7x-8y+14=0$, prove that the straight line given by $7x+6y=13$ is a tangent and find the point of contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

given parabola : $y^2-7x-8y+14=0$,

given line : $7x+6y=13$

point of contact : $y^2-7x-8y+14=y^2+(6y-13)-8y+14=0$ i.e., $y^2-2y+1=0$

i.e., $y=1$ i.e., $(1,1)$ is "the" point of contact

when "a" point of contact is "the" point of contact.. It must be tangent...

Comment: You gave the OP the full answer. He didn't provide any thoughts of his own.

Comment: +1. However ... "[W]hen 'a' point of contact is 'the' point of contact.. It must be tangent..." Careful. A line parallel to the axis of the parabola has only one point of contact, but it *is not* tangent. (Of course, the given line is clearly not parallel to the axis in this case, but you might want to state this explicitly.)

Comment: @Blue : yes yes... I should have written that explicitly.... :) :)

Comment: I didn't think of this method actually, I thought of the method mentioned by Thomas but wasn't sure if I could apply it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First find the derivative using implicit differentiation.

Then you want to find the point where the slope of the tangent is $-7/6$. That is, you ask the question: When is the derivative equal to $-7/6$? From what I can see, this equation will give you the $y$-coordinate to the point. Now take that and find the $x$-coordinate from the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Solve both the equations simultaneously, then you have a quadratic equation solve it.

> If the equation has **Discriminant**$>0$, then the line will be **Cutting.**
>
> If the equation has **Discriminant**$=0$, then the lone will be **Tangent.**
>
> If the equation has **Discriminant**$<0$, then the line will be **Non-Touching (outside).**